# Making Executable Sqlite Commands Android

Tags: android, sqlite

While learning the basics of Sqlite I continue to stumble across the same problem of understanding how sqlite commands are writen in Android
The sqlite commands are writen and exectuted like this...

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
      + TABLE_TODO
      + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_SUMMARY + " text not null," 
      + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION
      + " text not null" 
      + ");";

  public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }
```

However on the sqlite documentation they show something like this[image]

The data in the picture seems to greatly differ from the information given in the code.

Am I just reading the picture wrong, and if so can anyone explain to me how commands like this are setup or point me towards resources that explain how theses commands are setup.

Edit:
1. In the being it has rails that go off and say "temp" could that be added to "create table" to make "create temp table."

2. Lastly, what does "Without rowids" do. It is not in this command but if it was what would it do.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that you're reading the picture wrong, but I don't know how you're reading it. What do you think are the big differences?

Comment: To understand the SQL you have, have a look at the expanded `column-def` railroad diagram as well.

Comment: +BarbiePylon and +laalto I read it over and expanded column-def.  I understand it better now however I still have a few questions that I add to the post under Edit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *"The data in the picture seems to greatly differ from the information given in the code"* No, it is correct, you're reading the picture wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> In the being it has rails that go off and say "temp" could that be added to "create table" to make "create temp table."

Yes.

> Additionally, where in the code is "database-name" (in my code TABLE_TODO = todo, so is it not necessary to define a database name).

Yes, that may be omitted. Notice the arrow that goes below `database-name` and `.` in the diagram.

> Lastly, what does "Without rowids" do. It is not in this command but if it was what would it do.

By default, every table has an implicit `ROWID`. If the table has an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then it gets aliased with the `ROWID`. The `WITHOUT ROWID` is an optimization so that the implicit `ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column does not get generated. See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) for details.